# Searching a range of columns defined by variables in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to search a range of columns on a different worksheet, where the range is defined by two separate variables. I have successfully been able to use the same code to search a range of columns that I manually inputted, but using variables result in an error:

Run-time error '1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

I am using the code to search a separate worksheet for the column number of the first instance of the month and then search a range beginning with that column number for the specific day.

An example of the worksheet I'm searching through:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv34k.png

Below is the code. Specifically, the MonthFind function has worked perfectly, but the subsequent DayFind function, which uses output from MonthFind is acting up.

```
Private Sub ComboBox21_Change()

Dim i As String
Dim j As String

i = "February"
j = 9

Dim MonthFind As Variant

     With Sheets("Project Schedule").Range("A1:ZZ1")
    Set MonthFind = .Find(i, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

    End With

Dim Month1 As Integer
Dim Month2 As Integer

Month1 = MonthFind.Column
Month2 = MonthFind.Column + 12


Dim DayFind As Variant

    With Sheets("Project Schedule").Range(Columns(Month1), Columns(Month2))
 Set DayFind = .Find(j, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

 End With

End Sub
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've been trying so many different variations of this code to no avail!

Edit - Link to Excel file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/275fo0uucfeum3y/Project%20Scheduling%20SO.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Is this worksheet that you're searching against in another workbook?

Comment: No, this worksheet is in the same workbook as the current worksheet.

Comment: Thanks. I believe the issue is that the range isn't found (see my answer below)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I can't even do the check as the Run-time error 1004 keeps halting the program.

Comment: what line does that happen at? which part of the code?

Comment: The error occurs at the following line:
    With Sheets("Project Schedule").Range(Columns(Month1), Columns(Month2))

Comment: I ran your code and I can't repeat the error. Can you step through your code (add a breakpoint to the first line and step through with `F8`) and tell me what the values of `Month1` and `Month2` are when you get to the line that throws the error?

Comment: At the moment, Month1 = 20 and Month2 = 32, but that varies based on an ComboBox selection.

Comment: Where is this combo box? Is it in a UserForm? Or is it "baked" into the worksheet itself?

Comment: "Baked" into the worksheet itself. I could send the excel document if that would help.

Comment: Yes, that would help a lot. Please link it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost gave up on this, but I found out what the problem was.

Your `ComboBox_21` object has an input range (which will fill in the combobox with the selectable values) on the Inputs sheet that uses a bunch of formulas that reference the Project Schedule sheet. Whenever you do all those copy/paste functions against the range in Project Schedule that the combobox relies on, you are effectively changing the data for the dropdown box, and in turn, causing the `_Change()` event to fire off with every paste that effects that area.

This isn't always a problem (though in my opinion, it's causing a lot of unnecessary code execution), but there's this bit of code that is causing an issue in your `AddJob1_Click()` event:

`Range(Sheet1.Cells(erow, 5), Sheet1.Cells(erow + 3, 10000)).ClearContents`

Apparently you're not allowed to perform the `Range.Find()` method when the contents of the cells that the combobox rely on are being changed.

Here's some info about that, though it's not terribly helpful:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221581(v=office.11).aspx

So that's the why, now how to fix it:

**Defer automatic calculation until your UserForm code is finished doing whatever it needs to do.**

This will ensure that you are allowed to do the Find's and referencing you need to do.

```
Private Sub AddJob1_Click()
' turn off automatic calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

' ... other stuff

' turn calculation back on and perform a calculate, which will fire off the ComboBox21_Change() event    
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.Calculate

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful documentation and explanation. That definitely helped with issues with the ComboBox. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error code on the Employee Hours sheet when I try to run the code finding DayFind. I appreciate all of your help thus far and I'll understand if you've had more than enough with this project haha

Comment: Yeah, I noticed you are trying to do a lot in there. Step through your code with the debugging tools and try to see what's happening and when. Keep an eye on the Locals window, too. If you figure out where the problem is and are having a hard time with it, edit the question (but put "EDIT" at the end of your question and explain what's going on to keep the original question intact)